# find a desired sign inside the filename in matlab

Tags: regex, string, matlab, file-io, filenames

I have files with various names. I know their endings, like: ....known_file_end.mat. I would like to check if there is some number in the name, just before .known_file_end.mat and if so, remove it. How could I do it the most robust way?

I wonder also if it is possible, that I can check if there is an integer number for example in the beginning of the filename, so in the area that I have no idea about.

any help appreciated,
cheers!

Comment: Not clear exactly what you want to do. Actually change the name of the file in the filesystem, or do something else with the modified filename? Do you want to do this with MATLAB code, or from the Windows command prompt, or from a unix prompt, or something else?

Comment: Anyway, the very first link when you do a google search for `matlab regex` looks like it could be useful if you need to write some code in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use a regular expression to check for a number in the file name. If you only deal with integers, you can try to match against the pattern `\d+\.known_file_end\.mat`, i.e. one or more digits followed by the string `.known_file_end.mat`.

In Matlab this would look something like

```
pattern = '\d+\.known_file_end\.mat';
~isempty(regexp('something_10.known_file_end.mat', pattern))  % returns true
~isempty(regexp('something.known_file_end.mat', pattern))  % returns false
```

By modifying the `\d+` part in the pattern, you can also check for more complicated numbers, e.g. for simple decimal numbers use `\d+\.\d+`, which is one or more digits followed by a period followed by one or more digits.

Comment: when i have such a name: 2name20121304.05.mat
and I want to delete only the beginning integer, '2', how to do it?

Comment: You could use `regexprep(file_name, '^\d+', '')`, which replaces one or more digits **at the beginning** of a string (the `^` matches the start of the string).

Comment: or is there a possibility to detect such a combination: dot with integers after it ?

Comment: The dot in an regexp is a special character and thus has to be escaped with a backslash. An optional minus sign is matched by -? and [+-]? matches a plus or minus or nothing. So I'd suggest using '\.[+-]?\d+'.